# Classification of messages using Jess Rule in Protege

Tags: classification, ontology, protege, rule, jess

Hello I am trying to form a Jess rule in Jess Tab in Protege 3.4 I am new in Jess. I have an ontology with a class Message and 3 datatype properties : interests , category and class . The rule works as follows if the interests lists of a message is equal to category list of a message the message is ham.

I mapped my Message class using : (mapclass prefix:Message) and here is my rule. First the rule leads to infinite loop and only modifies the class of 1 instance . What am I doing wrong ?When I print only it is successful but the modification which is the base of my work does not , please help urgently.The rule is

```
defrule print_message_cat_int_modify
(object (is-a ..#Message) (OBJECT ?o)
(object ( ...#interests $?i) (OBJECT ?o))
(object ( ..#category $?c) (OBJECT ?o))
(object ( ..#id ?id) (OBJECT ?o))
=> (if (eq (intersection$ $?c $?i) () ) then (printout t "spam" crlf)
(modify-instance ?o (..#class spam)) else (printout t "ham" crlf) (modify-
instance ?o (..#class ham))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you match a fact in a rule and then modify that fact, if the rule still matches the modified fact, the rule will be fired again. YOu have to write the rule such that once the fact is modified, the rule no longer matches. In your case, this might would involve matching the "#class" value and excluding the ones you're going to change it to.

Comment: I am matching several facts they depend on the number of messages which is variable and the case id I want the rule value to match ( ham for example ) as long as the interests and category did not change ( if they change and were not equal fr example then it shall be spam .Can you show me by modifying my defrule , I am new in jess and need the code this week.Thank you.